# Beginner Haskell | Group List of Ints

Tags: list, haskell

I'm trying to make a function that makes a list of list of ints, can you lend a hand?

```
groupUp :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
```

example:

```
groupUp [1,2,2,3,3,3] == [[1],[2,2],[3,3,3]]
```

The closest I could come was:

```
groupUp [] = [[]]
groupUp (x:[]) = []            
groupUp(x:y:xs)
 | x==y       = [x,y] : groupUp (xs)
 | otherwise  = [x] : groupUp (y:xs)
```

But this limits the list to a group of maximum 2 (pairs) and not more. What should I change?

Edit: this one works, thx for the help!

```
  groupUp xs= helper 0 xs
        where helper _ []=[] 
              helper i xs= takeWhile (==(xs!!i))xs: helper (i) (dropWhile (==(xs!!i))xs)
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Sry hope this is better

Comment: I like that you posted your own version, however to be honest, this is awkward, inefficient and unsafe. Avoid using `!!`, `head` or `tail`, these will crash your program when given empty lists or something outside the range. Prefer safe library functions ot pattern-matching, then the compiler can warn you if you've missed some edge case.

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Avoiding_partial_functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of laborously comparing single elements, use a function that compares elements *until some condition*.

```
Prelude> span (==2) [2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]
([2,2],[3,3,3,4,4,4,4])
```

Then, recurse, using the remainder of that:

```
groupUp [] = [[]]   -- This should probably just be [], not [[]].
groupUp (x:xs) = case span (==x) xs of
     (thisGroup, others) -> (x:thisGroup) : groupUp others
```

Of course you can also define a version of [span](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:span) yourself if you prefer.

Comment: Would'nt the list be inside a tuple then? I want them to be in a list?

Comment: @ErikHNguyen Where did you get the idea that this would be inside a tuple? There are no tuples returned in the above function `groupUp`. Try it for yourself. The function `span` was used as a stepping stone to the function `groupUp`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I am just not familiar with the "case" "of" example. Where can i read more about it? I did another another fuction wich proably is exactly the same as yours.

Comment: @ErikHNguyen `case...of` is explained in any general Haskell tutorial. It does help to read one of the standard books... [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), albeit a bit outdated by now, is still my recommendation.